# Compare two files' modification time using Perl

Tags: perl, date, compare, stat

I’m trying to compare the modification time of two files (that are being created on the same machine) using [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) just to know which file is older.

I have tried the `–M` and [stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) and for some reason the results are not consistency. This is an example for what I have tried:

```
if ((stat($FileA))[9] < (stat("FileB"))[9]) {
```

This line sometimes work, but sometimes the results are just the opposite (the comparison should be at a seconds level and not just day \ hour).

Comment: What you're doing should work, so without more context, we can't tell what's going wrong. Did you mean for `$FileA` to be a variable and `"FileB"` a literal string? Did you look at the actual modification times outside of Perl (e.g. with `ls`)?

Comment: Either using `-M` or `(stat(...))[9]` should work. The error is probably elsewhere, e.g. maybe you are accessing a non-existent file (which would cause an undef value to be returned).

Comment: 1) Add `use strict; use warnings;` and fix issues. 2) Update question, include more relevant code (such as showing how you know its not working).

Comment: It is truly amazing to me that Perl has no equivalent of bash's `test $f1 -nt $f2`. Seriously, can that be true?

Answer (score 1):

Simply fix your syntax error: replace "FileB" with $fileB.